# Configure workspaces to use s3 storage class in tekton

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, continuous-integration, tekton

I want to configure my tekton pipelines to use S3 workspaces
Official tekton documentation https://tekton.dev/docs/getting-started/ has a section which says to delete config-artifact-pvc configMap and replace it with config-artifact-bucket configMap with the Aws secret and key. I followed this process however everytime I create a pipeline it still uses a PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-artifact-bucket
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
data:
  location: s3://mybucket
  bucket.service.account.secret.name: tekton-storage
  bucket.service.account.secret.key: boto-config
  bucket.service.account.field.name: BOTO_CONFIG
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tekton-storage
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
type: kubernetes.io/opaque
stringData:
  boto-config: |
    [Credentials]
    aws_access_key_id = xxxx
    aws_secret_access_key = xxxx
    [s3]
    host = xxxx
    [Boto]
    https_validate_certificates = False
```

Do I need to have a custom s3 storage class setup before I configure tekton to use s3 buckets for my workspaces

My pipeline run still uses a claim template to backup my workspace. How do I change it to use a s3 bucket?

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  generateName: hello-
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: hello
  workspaces:
    - name: output
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec: 
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi
```

Is there an example of a taskrun or pipeline run which are backed by s3?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way the `volumeClaimTemplate` is defined. If you run `kubectl get storageclass` and look in the name column you will note that one has the text `(default)`. In the absence of declaring a the storage class, the default will be chosen. To fix this set the `spec.workspaces.volumeClaimTeamplte.spec.storageClassName` field.

I am using IBM Cloud (for example), so I would (using the output of `kubectl get storageclass`) set `storageClassName` to `"ibmc-s3fs-standard-regional"`:

```
workspaces:
  - name: output
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec: 
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        storageClassName: "ibmc-s3fs-standard-regional"
```